# Flutter FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)

Tags: json, flutter, http

In flutter, i use a php file which returns a json response from a db query, but when i try to decode json i getting this error:

```
E/flutter ( 8294): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled
Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter ( 8294): ï»¿[{"0":"PRUEBA","usu_nombre":"PRUEBA"}]
E/flutter ( 8294): ^
```

Here is my dart function:

```
Future<String> iniciarSesion() async{
var usuario = textUsuario.text;
var password = textPassword.text;
var nombreUsuario;
var url ="http://192.168.1.37/usuario.php";

//Metodo post
var response = await http.post(
    url,
    headers:{ "Accept": "application/json" } ,
    body: { "usuario": '$usuario',"password": '$password'},
    encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8")
);
  List data = json.decode(response.body);
}
```

And code from my php file:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

include_once "Clases/conexion.php";

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$consulta = "select usu_nombre
FROM usu_usuarios
WHERE usu_nusuario='$usuario'and usu_password='$password' and  usu_activo='SI'";

$mysql_obj = new Conectar();
$mysqli = $mysql_obj->crearConexion();

if($result = $mysqli->query($consulta)) {
if ($mysqli->affected_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $myArray[] = $row;
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($myArray);
}else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 401 Datos Incorrectos");
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $data = array("mensaje" => "Datos Incorrectos");
    echo json_encode($data);
}}
?>
```

I'm using HTTP dart dependence

Comment: Hi, I'm having kinda the same issue, did you find what is wrong and what was the solution please?

Comment: @user2682025 Hi, check my answer below please :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Solve this issue with folowing code. For more refer [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32841).

```
var pdfText= await json.decode(json.encode(response.databody);
```

Comment: fully working on Flutter 2.0.6 engine! Thanks a lot lot! [:

Comment: this is the answer. Thanks. but why it showing such a behaviour?

Comment: This works like charm thanks man <3

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Dio and facing this kind of error then add :

```
 responseType: ResponseType.plain,
```

to your dio client.
Complete dio client is as follows:

```
final Dio _dio = Dio(BaseOptions(
connectTimeout: 10000,
receiveTimeout: 10000,
baseUrl: ApiEndPoints.baseURL,
contentType: 'application/json',
responseType: ResponseType.plain,
headers: {
  HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjQxNTU5MzYzLCJqdGkiOiJlOTBiZjIyYjI5YTg0YmRhYWNlZmIxZTY0Y2M2OTk1YyIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjF9.aDQzoYRawmXUCLxzEW8mb4e9OcR4L8YhcyjQIaBFUxk'
},
```

)
)

Comment: how about pure http ? ResponseType.plain, undefined , i have same issue on format exception for success: true , from json.

Answer (score 8):

Finally i resolve the problem using laravel, returning the data in this way

```
return response()->json($yourData, 200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Charset' => 'utf-8'],
    JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
```

I have noticed that this error occurs only in emulator, but not in a physical device.

Answer (score 4):

Finally I resolve the problem in flutter, requesting the data in this way:

```
Map<String, String> headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'Charset': 'utf-8'
};

http.get('localhost:8000/users', headers: headers)
```

Answer (score 3):

`FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) Try again ^`

The error is from flutter. It probably happened because you catch the http response using an **object model**, but your api response actually is a **string** or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error on Android because I was using insecure http connections without setting  application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"/ in the AndroidManifest.

Answer (score 1):

If you are requesting Multipart or Form-data then try to convert the response into simple http response using `http.Response.fromStream(response)`

Full code :

```
 String baseUrl ="https://yourUrl.com";
        var uri = Uri.parse(baseUrl);
        var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
        request.headers.addAll(headers);
        var multipartFile = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
            "file", videoFile.path);
        request.files.add(multipartFile);
        await request.send().then((response) {
        http.Response.fromStream(response).then((value) {
        print(value.statusCode);
        print(value.body);
        var cloudFlareResponse =
        CloudFlareApi.fromJson(json.decode(value.body));
        print(cloudFlareResponse.result.playback.hls);
        });
```

Comment: I'm using Multipart and this worked for me like a magic

Answer (score 1):

It may cause by Nginx image, file size limitation. Which will override your API response and your API returns the following error instead of your own defined error response structure:

```
I/flutter (25662): <html>

I/flutter (25662): <head><title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title></head>

I/flutter (25662): <body>

I/flutter (25662): <center><h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1></center>

I/flutter (25662): <hr><center>nginx/1.20.0</center>

I/flutter (25662): </body>

I/flutter (25662): </html>
```

If this is the issue, you can change allowed file, image size from your server Nginx settings to prevent this or check and resize image file before sending it thru your API.

You need to see what is the real error before trying to fix it.
To make sure what is the real error, print the response before json decode and casting to map line like below:

```
debugPrint('Response body before decoding and casting to map: ');
      debugPrint(response.body.toString()); // this will print whatever the response body is before throwing exception or error


      Map responseMap = json.decode(response.body);
      debugPrint('responseMap is: ');
      debugPrint(responseMap.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was due to the wrong URL. I mistakenly placed two / after my base URL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are getting the `ï»¿` before your response, but I think it expects `{` as the first character, which is not true for your scenario. Have you added `ï»¿` yourself or do you know why it is a part of the response?
If you can make it respond `{"0":"PRUEBA","usu_nombre":"PRUEBA"}` you should be home safe.

Why do you want to save your data as a List rather than a String? By having it as a String rather than a List you avoid the square brackets around your response.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do not know where those symbols come from but I'm sure I do not add them to the response.

Answer (score 0):

That works for me, there was a problem with http ( http package ) and i replace it with httpClient from dart:io

Future login(String email, String password) async {

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
const url = "http://127.0.0.1/api/auth/login";
Map data = {
  "email": email,
  "password": password,
};
var body = json.encode(data);
HttpClientRequest request = await httpClient.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));
request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(data)));
HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
String reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
httpClient.close();
print(reply);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For me, changing the URL part from:
"http://localhost:3001/mypage"
to
"http://127.0.0.1:3001/mypage"
resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

This works on flutter.
I was using Stream and i had to change this code `response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder)` to

```
final decodedResponse = await utf8.decoder.bind(response.stream).join();
return Stream.value(decodedResponse);
```

```
Future<Stream> createWithImage(User user , File image )                  async  {
        try{

        Uri url = Uri.http(_url,'$_api/create');


        final request = http.MultipartRequest('POST',url);
        if(image != null){
            request.files.add(http.MultipartFile(
                'image',
                http.ByteStream(image.openRead().cast()),
                await image.length(),
                filename: basename(image.path)
            ));
        }
        Map<String,String> headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Charset': 'utf-8'
        };
        request.headers.addAll(headers);

        request.fields['user'] = json.encode(user);
        final response = await request.send(); //Enviara la peticion



        // Adaptar la transformación UTF-8
        final decodedResponse = await utf8.decoder.bind(response.stream).join();

        return Stream.value(decodedResponse);



    }catch(e){
        print('Error : $e');
        throw Exception('Network Error: $e');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use dio method for api calling please use like ,
your porblem is 100% solved

Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(response.toString());

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me to capture the token and implement the body of the headers:

```
Future<List> getData() async {
   final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   final key = 'token';
   final value = prefs.get(key ) ?? 0;
 
   final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://tuapi"),  headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
   'Charset': 'utf-8',
   "Authorization" : "Bearer $value"
   });
   return json.decode(response.body);

   }
```