# Exception has occurred. FormatException (FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> ^ )

Tags: laravel, flutter

I want cannot post data from flutter emulator to database.
This is the error I got after run the emulator and enter the data.

> Exception has occurred.
>   FormatException (FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
>   
>   ^
>   )

this is my **api.dart**
import 'dart:convert';

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
class CallApi{
    final String _url = 'http://10.2.2.0/voyceb/api/';

    postData(data, apiUrl) async {
        var fullUrl = _url + apiUrl + await _getToken(); 
        return await http.post(
            fullUrl, 
            body: jsonEncode(data), 
            headers: _setHeaders()
        );
    }
    getData(apiUrl) async {
       var fullUrl = _url + apiUrl + await _getToken(); 
       return await http.get(
         fullUrl, 
         headers: _setHeaders()
       );
    }

    _setHeaders() => {
        'Content-type' : 'application/json',
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
    };

    _getToken() async {
        SharedPreferences localStorage = await
        SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        var token = localStorage.getString('token');
        return '?token=$token';
    }
}
```

the error shown at part in **signup.dart**

```
var res = await CallApi().postData(data, 'register');
var body = json.decode(res.body);
```

error shown at

> var body = json.decode(res.body);

at json.decode.

I want data to be insert to database as I enter in emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's a problem on JSON encode and decode process.

You may solve that using this

```dart
var res = await CallApi().postData(data, 'register');
var encodeFirst = json.encode(res.body);
var data = json.decode(encodeFirst);
```

Comment: or maybe theres an issue on your Laravel server. 
possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55671441/flutter-formatexception-unexpected-character-at-character-1/55677287

Comment: i dont think so. I think my error is different because it also display this error. ><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you need to check yours .htacess file.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the request is not successful. You should decode the response body after checking the response code is 200.