# When starting Hot Reload, an error is thrown (FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1))

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart

I'm trying to send a request from a site that works at http://flat.imruz.com/api/sliders and http://flat.imruz.com/api/categories В
The api code works well in the browser. And when I run it on the emulator, it throws an error (FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)).
I'll attach the flutter screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your API endpoint returns HTML instead of a JSON. Make sure that:

- the endpoint URL is valid,
- your request is valid and the API handles errors properly,
- you've added a `'Content-type': 'application/json'` header,
- you are authorized to access the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Check this article 
[Flutter FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55671441/flutter-formatexception-unexpected-character-at-character-1)
And first google then create a thread.
And check that 
https://issue.life/questions/57473788
There in Russian, but at the end there is a link not a git hub with answers

Answer (score 0):

You have double slash in you final url generated

replace this

```
String _baseUrl = 'http://flat.imruz.com/api/';
```

with this

```
String _baseUrl = 'http://flat.imruz.com/api'
```