# Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) error

Tags: flutter

Whenever I start or restart the app I get this error:

```
E/flutter (11521): #46     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framewor
E/flutter (11521): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter (11521): <!DOCTYPE html>
E/flutter (11521): ^
E/flutter (11521):
```

PLEASE HELP...

Comment: My guess would be you are having an illegal character at the start of your main.dart file. It would be very helpful if you could provide more details (like list your code).

Comment: it should be about your code. can you look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55671441/flutter-formatexception-unexpected-character-at-character-1

Comment: I think its from backend error.. check ur api response