# Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) <asynchronous suspension>

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetProducts() async {
final url = Uri.https('flutter-project-c43e5-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com',
    '/products.json?auth=$authToken');
try {
  final response = await http.get(url);
  final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  if (extractedData == null) {
    return;
  }
  final List<Product> loadedProducts = [];
  extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
    loadedProducts.add(Product(
      id: prodId,
      title: prodData['title'],
      description: prodData['description'],
      price: prodData['price'],
      isFavorite: prodData['isFavorite'],
      imageUrl: prodData['imageUrl'],
    ));
  });
  _items = loadedProducts;
  notifyListeners();
} catch (error) {
  throw (error);
}
```

}

I am getting this error
Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
not found
I have tried everything and I am not using dio
Can someone tell what is wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55671441/flutter-formatexception-unexpected-character-at-character-1)

Comment: You didn't check `response.statusCode`, so likely you're trying to parse a failure page that isn't JSON.

Answer (score 0):

why do you have a `,` in your url?:

```dart
Future<void> fetchAndSetProducts() async {
final url = Uri.https('flutter-project-c43e5-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com',
    '/products.json?auth=$authToken');
...
```

change this block to:

```dart
Future<void> fetchAndSetProducts() async {
final url = Uri.https('flutter-project-c43e5-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/products.json?auth=$authToken');
...
```

Comment: https requires two arguments in that format only else it shows error

Comment: Ok, perhaps you should use the original format as in the course? I took this course and have passed this stage without errors.