# Flutter : Navigate to Welcome Screen after Successful Signup

Tags: mysql, json, database, flutter, dart

I try to navigate to WelcomeScreen after the user successfully signup, but it does not do so although it works fine with Login screen and I receive this error :

> I/flutter ( 5046): FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
> I/flutter ( 5046): user added successfully
> I/flutter ( 5046): ^'

here is my code:

```
Future signup(BuildContext cont) async{
  var url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/localconnect/signup.php";
  var response = await http.post(url, body: {
    'username' : username.text,
    'password' : password.text,
  });

  try {
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    Navigator.push(cont, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>WelcomeScreen()));
  }catch(e){
    print(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: [I found the answer here :](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65552861/4540284) var data = await json.decode(json.encode(response.body));

Answer (score 1):

You have to put condition on statuscode of response, and on the value of response too like,

```
Future signup(BuildContext cont) async{
var url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/localconnect/signup.php";
var response = await http.post(url, body: {
'username' : username.text,
'password' : password.text,
});
try {
var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
if(response.statuscode==200){
if(data['status']) {//status is bool from APi.
Navigator.push(cont, MaterialPageRoute(builder: 
(context)=>WelcomeScreen()));
}
}
}catch(e){
print(e);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to send data like this :  use `jsonEncode` for body. As you are getting response in string means thats error thats why you are getting like that. Or you can share api response so, can get idea.

```
 var response = await http.post(url, body: jsonEncode({
    'username' : username.text,
    'password' : password.text,
  }));
```

Comment: I tried using jsonEncode for body but still stuck in the same error

Comment: Can you share response or  log this : print(response.body)

Comment: it just need json encode to be done this way: var data = await json.decode(json.encode(response.body));