# DioError [DioErrorType.other]: FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 9, character 1)

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

this is my Dio :

```
class DioHelper {
  static late Dio dio;
  static init() {
    dio = Dio(BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: "https://management.rawcodev.com/api/",
      receiveDataWhenStatusError: true,
      //this will not throw error "DioError DioErrorType.response: Http status error 422"
      validateStatus: (status) => true,
// headers: {

// }
    ));
  }

  static Future<Response> getData({
    required String path,
    Map<String, dynamic>? query,
    String lang = "en",
    String? token,
  }) async {
    dio.options.headers = {
      "lang": lang,
      "Authorization": token,
      "Content-Type": "application/json"

    };
    return await dio.get(path, queryParameters: query);
  }}
```

i try to send the same data in the postman header but i get error 400

"Host":"",

"User-Agent":"PostmanRuntime/7.32.2",

"Accept":"*/*",

"Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",

"Connection":"keep-alive",

the function to get data in cubit:

```
Attendance_History_Model? attendHistoryModel;
  void getAttendHistory() {
    emit(AttendanceHistoryLoding());
    DioHelper.getData(path: AttendHistory, query: {
      "mod": "attendance-history",
      "key": "ABC@123",
      "user_id": user_idconst,
      "device_id": "device-1"
    }).then((value) {
      if (value.statusCode == 200) {
        attendHistoryModel = Attendance_History_Model.fromJson(value.data);
        // print(attendHistoryModel!.attendenceHistory![1].dayTotalWorkingHours);
        emit(AttendanceHistorySuccess());
      } else {
        print("error");
        print(value.statusCode);
      }
    }).catchError((error) {
      print( error.toString());
      emit(AttendanceHistoryError());
    });
  }
```

i try to change the way to save json in model to :
[image]

but still isn't work

when i run i get this error:
DioError [DioErrorType.other]: FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 9, character 1)
[image]

in postman is it work
[image]

can any one help me to solve it and explain the issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55671441/flutter-formatexception-unexpected-character-at-character-1)

Comment: isn't work this answer to me

Comment: i edit my post you can check 
@Monasha

Comment: you are not giving a token to the getData function, but in the header the option is there maybe this is the problem. in postman you don't set any authorization header.

Comment: also in the vs code log, you can see the unexpected charactars are '<br />', maybe this is also a hint

Comment: when i set the same header in postman in my function i get error 400 in my code

Comment: This error often occurs with invalid JSONs. So first you could try running in debugger mode and put a debugger point at line 87 and check if the returning JSON is valid using an online formatter tool.